# In some of the mac os and chrome browser ace editor autocomplete popup is not working

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

```js
api.subscribe((res)=>{
 callback(null, res.suggestion.map((ea)=> {
          return {
            name: `${ea.text ? ea.text.trim() : ''}`,
            value: `${ea.text}`,
            meta: (ea.type ? _.capitalize(ea.type) : '') ,
            completer: {
              insertMatch:  (editor, data)=> {
                if (editor.completer.completions.filterText) {
                  var ranges = editor.selection.getAllRanges();
                  for (var i = 0, range; range = ranges[i]; i++) {
                    range.start.column -= editor.completer.completions.filterText.length;
                    editor.session.remove(range);
                  }
                }
                editor.execCommand("insertstring", this.getEditorInsertValue(data.bqlKind, data.value));
              },
            }
          }
        } 
})
```

In some of the mac os and chrome browser ace editor autocomplete popup is not working
[I have attache a screenshot for the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpS8L.png)

below are the details of browser :

**Chrome Version 80.0.3987.132 on macOS Catalina Version 10.15.3**

and currently I am using 
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.5/ace.js and 
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.5/ext-language_tools.js

Attaching a code snippet for reference :

Comment: does the same happen on https://ace.c9.io/?

Comment: No, I have implemented for my use case, attached screenshot for the same as well

Comment: that means there is a bug in your code, try creating a minimal example reproducing the issue, most likely you will find the solution yourself when working on that minimal example.